# nested json object to a one to many model in polymer

Tags: json, polymer, object-model

just starting with polymer, and need an opinion about using pure javascript Objects as my model vs polymer elements. I have a nested json object I want to map to a multiple one to many custom objects e.g.
Company -> Departments -> Teams -> Employees

I already did the model above using pure javascript Objects as the code below.

I have a separate function for every entity above based on the pattern below. Now As I understand  polymer elements can either be UI related or utility. Any suggestion to make the model more tied to polymer or just stick with keeping the model as below. Thanks in advance for insights.

```
function Company (json){
   this.companyID = null;
   this.companyName = null;
   this.Departments = null
   for (var prop in json){ 
        if(this[prop] !== undefined && json[prop] != null ){ 
          var iterator = json[prop]
          if(   iterator.constructor === Array  ){  
            for(var i in iterator){
              var newDepartment = new Department(iterator[i]);
              if(this.Departments == null) this.Departments = []; 
              this.Departments.push(newDepartment);
            }

          }else{
            this[prop] = iterator;
          }
        }
      };

}
```

Comment: updated the answer to include an example for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually a number of talks regarding this subject starting from before these custom markup libraries started hitting the web. The most persuasive one being [Web Components and Model Driven Views](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.confreaks.com%2Fvideos%2F2204-fronteersconf2011-web-components-and-model-driven-views&ei=ftnOVLX7KsiVyATw4YJg&usg=AFQjCNEYTuesH9VS78xHQivTXiituxmQBA&sig2=EbpoR3wkuZKx00w8uzfJcA&bvm=bv.85076809,d.aWw). This video argues for markup based components and modeling in the front-end and for a number of practical and social reasons.

Focusing specifically on Polymer, there is very little reason to have pure javascript models if there is to be any sort of view attached to them. Reasons for this (aside from the video) include:

- 9 times out of 10, you are just duplicating a model that is somewhere in the back-end (if you use a back-end framework or storage orm)
- This will often result in rendering the model with DOM manipulation. This can be handled easily with Polymer.
- Javascript is supposed to be there to do what the web platform cannot natively. Custom markup fixes a lot of that.
- Data-Binding and Template-Binding bridge a lot of the issues that MVC solves as a practice. MVC is (and has been) a necessary step, but often for the same reasons that MDV tries to solve out of the box.
- Unless your application is a pure Javascript application, most times your client is supposed to be the View which gets the Model from the server. Using custom markup ***can*** provide a cleaner separation.
- According to the Polymer docs on [Data Binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding.html), the model is the element itself. This is obviously, to the devs of Polymer, what it was designed for.

That said, there are plenty of reasons for using a pure Javascript model. I haven't found many that can't be addressed (and addressed well) by utilizing data/template binding, though I have found some. The more I work with Polymer, the smaller that list becomes as I learn newer Polymer techniques that address concerns on that list.

**Note on Personal Bias:**

Keep in mind that all of the above are biased by my personal view that the development ecosystem for a platform should strive to meet the ideals proposed by that platform. Polymer is the first framework I have found that epitomizes that. The Custom Markup can now easily describe the Content and the presentation layer. And I can rely on a strong storage scheme in the back-end to manage my Model and its data. So for me, the separation of concerns is clear.

**Update: An example of One-to-Many Model**

This example assumes a single object for your model. Of course, it is quite simple to account for separate objects and is the basis of many model-based UIs.

***Company Element***

```
<polymer-element name="x-company" attributes="company" noscript>
    <template>
        <!-- Top of Company UI -->
        <template repeat="{{department in company.departments}}">
            <x-department department="{{department}}">
            </x-department>
        </template>
        <content><content>   <!-- Insertion point for DOM children -->
        <!-- Bottom of Company UI -->
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

The above is fairly simple. To actually apply the company data, simply get the node and set `.company = { obj }`... or if in the template of another element, `company="{{ ref }}"`. Note the noscript at the top. It is purely for simplicity and is completely optional. One note: company.departments should be an array of objects. If you do use a script, there is a lot more that can be done with your UI.

***Department***

```
<polymer-element name="x-department" attributes="department" noscript>
    <template>
        <!-- Top of Department UI -->
        <template repeat="{{team in department.teams}}">
            <x-team team="{{team}}">
            </x-team>
        </template>
        <content><content>   <!-- Insertion point for DOM children -->
        <!-- Bottom of Department UI -->
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

***Team***

```
<polymer-element name="x-team" attributes="team" noscript>
    <template>
        <!-- Top of Team UI -->
        <template repeat="{{employee in team.employees}}">
            <x-employee employee="{{employee}}">
            </x-employee>
        </template>
        <content><content>   <!-- Insertion point for DOM children -->
        <!-- Bottom of Team UI -->
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

***Employee***

```
<polymer-element name="x-employee" attributes="employee" noscript>
    <template>
        <!-- Top of Employee UI -->
        <content><content>   <!-- Insertion point for DOM children -->
        <!-- Bottom of Team UI -->
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

That's as simple as your model's UI can be. There are a lot of other possibilities. This makes pure use of Shadow DOM, but you may use plenty of other techniques to apply the model to the Light DOM and Content children.

Hopefully, this clears things up for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed response, however I king of got lost in the polymer databinding part. How would i address the one to may relationship between polymer elements

Comment: Certainly, I interpreted your question to be whether to and not how. Give me a bit to compose a solution.